# Bash run a program and repeatedly pass it data

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, automation

I need to write a bash script to run a program and then every 5 seconds pass data to this program. The program accepts command line input and then will return some data.
 I currently have

```
./a &
while true
do
  echo "input 1"
  echo "input 2"
  sleep 5
done
```

But this doesn't do what I'm after. The data being passed each time will be the same and the program cannot be restarted. How would I go about this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Param1=*.txt

while true
do
  Output=`ls -1 ${Param1}`
  echo "Output: ${Output}"  
  sleep 5
done
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand you correctly:

some_program.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == 1 ]; then
echo equals 1
  else
echo not equals 1
fi
```

run_script.sh

```
#/bin/bash

while true
do 
./some_program.sh 1
./some_program.sh 2
sleep 5
done
```

Or you need to run program in the background and then pass data?

Comment: The script will start a program, a, through ./a and I need to then pass it data in a loop. In essence start a program and every 5 seconds supply that program, which has a command line interface, with 2 strings of data

Comment: So you can run your programm listening some file or variable and then pass your data into this variable or file https://askubuntu.com/questions/439432/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-script-which-will-run-in-background is this something you looking for?

Comment: Similar but that question calls the program every loop iteration which I can't do. The program can only be run once, then the loop has to happen with the data being passed to it

Comment: @noptim: What is it you want this to do, precisely?

Comment: Are you trying to pass new command line arguments to the program after it has started?